# How to swap odd and even lines in a text file?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file. I have to swap odd and even lines.

I made a batch script that writes even lines into `testfile2.txt` and odd lines into `testfile3.txt`.

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "filepath1=C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\testfile.txt"
set "filepath2=C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\testfile2.txt"
set "filepath3=C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\testfile3.txt"
set counter=0
set B=0
for /F %%A in (%filepath1%) do (
set /a B=!counter!%%2
if !B! equ 0 (echo %%A>>%filepath2%) else (echo %%A>>%filepath3%)
set /A counter=counter+1
)
```

And I want to take 1 line from file that contains odd lines, then 1 line from the file with even lines and write it to my first file. But I don't understand how to do it in **FOR** loop because it reads a line from only one file and I can't work with another file in this loop.

Example of input file:

```
1a
2b
3c
4d
```

Example of output file:

```
2b
1a
4d
3c
```

Comment: Why do each of your filepath's have double backslashes? Every single file path on every PC I've ever used has a single backslash.

Comment: it`s my habit,it works

Comment: It's [wrong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#paths), change your bad habit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions for this task.

The first one uses delayed expansion on execution of all lines of batch file exchanging odd and even lines. This means it does not work right for lines with an exclamation in line because `!` is removed from line.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile.txt"
if not exist "%SourceFile%" goto EndBatch
set "TargetFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile2.txt"
del "%TargetFile%" 2>nul

set "LineOdd="
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%SourceFile%") do (
    if not defined LineOdd (
        set "LineOdd=%%I"
    ) else (
        echo %%I>>"%TargetFile%"
        echo !LineOdd!>>"%TargetFile%"
        set "LineOdd="
    )
)

if defined LineOdd echo !LineOdd!>>"%TargetFile%"
move /Y "%TargetFile%" "%SourceFile%"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Blank and empty lines are skipped by **FOR** and therefore missing in target file. And lines starting with a semicolon `;` are ignored on reading each line by **FOR** and for that reason are missing also in output file. But those limitations should not matter here according to input example.

The limitations of first solution could be avoided using this batch code which is of course much slower:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile.txt"
if not exist "%SourceFile%" goto EndBatch
set "TargetFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile2.txt"
del "%TargetFile%" 2>nul

set "LineOdd="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%H in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^" "%SourceFile%"') do (
    if not defined LineOdd (
        set "LineOdd=_%%I"
    ) else (
        if "%%I" == "" (
            echo/>>"%TargetFile%"
        ) else (
            echo %%I>>"%TargetFile%"
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if "!LineOdd!" == "_" (
            echo/>>"%TargetFile%"
        ) else (
            echo !LineOdd:~1!>>"%TargetFile%"
        )
        endlocal
        set "LineOdd="
    )
)

if defined LineOdd (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if "!LineOdd!" == "_" (
        echo/>>"%TargetFile%"
    ) else (
        echo !LineOdd:~1!>>"%TargetFile%"
    )
    endlocal
)
move /Y "%TargetFile%" "%SourceFile%"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

It would be also possible to use hybrid batch file [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by Dave Benham:

```
call jrepl.bat "^(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n" "$2\r\n$1\r\n" /M /X /F "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile.txt" /O "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile2.txt"
move /Y "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile2.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TestFile.txt"
```

The last line of the file must have a DOS/Windows line termination (carriage return \r and line-feed \n) if being an even line on using this solution.

For understanding the used commands/executables/batch files and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following command lines, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command/executable/batch file very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr.exe /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=textfile.txt"

rem // Count number of lines:
for /F %%C in ('^< "!_FILE!" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
rem // Divide by two, round up:
set /A "COUNT=(COUNT+1)/2"

< "!_FILE!" > "!_FILE!.tmp" (
    rem // Read files in blocks of two lines:
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        set "LINE1=" & set "LINE2="
        set /P LINE1=""
        set /P LINE2=""
        echo(!LINE2!
        echo(!LINE1!
    )
)

rem // Overwrite original file:
> nul move /Y "!_FILE!.tmp" "!_FILE!"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: You're welcome! What do you expect to happen with the last line in case the file contains an odd number of lines?

Answer (score 0):

The following example will create two files from `testfile.txt`, `file0.out` containing the even lines, and `file1.out` containing the odd lines.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" "testfile.txt"') Do (
    Set/A "_=%%A%%2"
    (Echo(%%B)>>file!_!.out)
```

*Rename the output files according to your requirements*.

Comment: I need to combine this to files in one file,taking one line from odd lines file,another from even lines file.

Comment: I need to swap all odd and even files with each other in one input textfile

Comment: Your question is not clear, it asks about odd and even lines, you're now asking about odd and even files. If you do not improve your post to better explain your problem it will probably be closed or continue to receive answers which do not satidfy you.

Answer (score 0):

I think to reinterleave the odd and even versions in reversed order isn't that difficult. Appending to Compo's try:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set File=testfile
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" "%File%.txt"'
) Do Set/A "_=%%A%%2"&>>%File%_!_!.txt Echo(%%B
<%File%_0.txt (For /f "delims=" %%A in (%File%_1.txt) Do (
    Set "B="&Set /P "B="
    Echo(!B!
    Echo(%%A
)) >%File%-new.txt
Del %File%_*
```

In case of an uneven total the second last line will be empty. sample Output:

```
2b
1a
4d
3c

5e
```